# Comparison of datetime in where condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to add a date comparison in a query.

The field is `column delivery_date timestamp without time zone`

The condition should be delivery_date <= today.

I have tried :

```
"delivery_date < ?", Date.today 

 delivery_date.lt(Date.today)

"delivery_date" <= time.now [Error : NameError - undefined local variable or method `time' for ]

"delivery_date" <= Time.now [Error  : ArgumentError - comparison of String with DateTime failed: ]
```

but I am getting different errors with all.

Here is the query where I need to add my condition :

```
datas: tab.project
          .active
          .where("delivery_date" <= date.today, step_id: Step::OPENED, test: {typess: type})
          .joins(:test, :account)
          .group(:'account.name')
          .order('count(tab.id) DESC')
          .count(:id)
```

Any idea how it should be done?

Comment: You have not either provided code block content properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
tab.project.active.where("delivery_date <= ?", Date.today)
```

or

```
tab.project.active.where("delivery_date <= :date", date: Date.today)
```

In both cases we use `Date.today` that returns (suprisingly :-) ) the date of today. We use two ways of adding param to a query -

- [array condition](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions) where `?` is replaced by next `where` arguments (in this case the `Date.today`)
- [placeholder condition](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#placeholder-conditions) where a symbol is replaced by a hash value for this symbol (`date: Date.today`)

Comment: It did not work. Error : ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid - wrong number of bind variables (2 for 1) in: delivery_date <= ?:

Comment: Try: `tab.project.active.where("delivery_date <= :date", date: Date.today)`

Comment: I think it worked. Thanks! I will test some more. Could you kindly explain the code to me. I don't understand it.

Comment: The problem is that you where jamming everything into a single call to `.where`. When you are using a string as the first argument the additional arguments need to match the placeholders in the SQL string.

Comment: So `.where("delivery_date <= ?", Date.today).where(foo: bar)` works while `where("delivery_date <= ?", Date.today, foo: bar)` will   give wrong number of bind variables.

Comment: `.where("delivery_date <= ?", Date.today)` and `.where("delivery_date <= :date", date: Date.today)`  are exactly the same in terms of results, the latter just uses named placeholders instead which can make the query more readable.

Comment: explained, please, consider upvoting if it helps :)